# Troubles with representing correct odoo form

Tags: python, odoo

I'm doing odoo tutorial and a have problem with correct representation of form.
[It should look like this in odoo tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwqsa.png)

[but it comes out differently when apply my xml file with form description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNMoD.png)

My xml settings:

```
<record id="estate_property_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">estate.property.form</field>
<field name="model">estate.property</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Lost Reason">
      <sheet>
          <h1 class="mb32">
              <field name="name" class="mb16"/>
          </h1>
          <group>
              <group>
                  <field name="property_type_id" string="Property Type"/>
                  <field name="postcode"/>
                  <field name="date_availability"/>
              </group>
              <group>
                  <field name="expected_price"/>
                  <field name="selling_price"/>
              </group>
              <notebook>
                  <page string="Description">
                    <group>
                        <field name="tag_ids" string="Tag" widget="many2many_tags"/>
                        <field name="description"/>
                        <field name="bedrooms"/>
                        <field name="living_area"/>
                        <field name="facades"/>
                        <field name="garage"/>
                        <field name="garden"/>
                        <field name="garden_area"/>
                        <field name="garden_orientation"/>
                        <field name="postcode"/>
                    </group>
                  </page>
              </notebook>
              <notebook>
                  <page string="Other info">
                    <group>
                        <field name="buyer"/>
                        <field name="salesperson"/>
                    </group>
                  </page>
              </notebook>
             <notebook>
                  <page string="Offers">
                    <group>
                        <field name="offer_ids"/>
                    </group>
                  </page>
              </notebook>
          </group>
      </sheet>
    </form>
</field>
```

I watched all tutorials all over, but didn't find any solution for my problem. Thanks for a help.

Comment: As addition to the answer(s): try to look in some existing (form) views, to learn how to create the Odoo look&feel. Good examples are form views for models res.partner and sale.order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created 3 different notebook tag which leads to give you output. Try with 1 notebook tag with 3 pages. It will give correct output.

Generally, 1 form view has 1 notebook tag.